# Gradient boosting in Python from scratch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, gradient-descent

How can least squares regression-based **gradient boosting** be written in Python? Sci-kit learn's gradient boosting package is all that ever comes up in search. No one seems to be implementing gradient boost from scratch, and if they do, it's limited to use on only univariate data. **How can gradient boosting be written in Python for multivariate data**? Algorithm 2 of the image below taken from [Friedman 2001](https://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/irwin.king/_media/presentations/2001_greedy_function_approximation_a_gradient_boosting_machine.pdf):

[image]

Comment: This library provides the functionality your are looking for: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html

Comment: what did you come up with? did you try to write it yourself? send us your code.

Comment: finding the regression coefficients per $m$ loop is simple enough using pseudo-residuals for the response variable, but not sure how to write the 2nd line of the loop in python code, where we minimize for the optimal $\rho$ so that the m'th model $F_m(x)$ is the previous model added by $\rho* \times$ the previous learner?

Comment: I have read that you use a line search in the rho parameter. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting where it says: "Compute multiplier γ m {\displaystyle \gamma _{m}} \gamma _{m} by solving the following one-dimensional optimization problem..." (wikipedia version calls it gamma.) If i implement this I'll post...

Answer (score 0):

Use a line search in the rho parameter. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting where it says: "Compute multiplier γ m {\displaystyle \gamma _{m}} \gamma _{m} by solving the following one-dimensional optimization problem..." (wikipedia version calls it gamma.)

I cant show my entire program, but here is the boosting:

```
from scipy import optimize

def gradient_boost(answers, outputs, last_answer, rho):
"""
    :param answers:  array of the target indices (integers)
    :param outputs:  current learner output matrix, nexamples x ntarget, 2d array with the examples in the rows and target index in the columns.
    :param last_answer: boost_last_answer, initialized to zeros, the size of the outputs.  This will accumulate the combined outputs
    :param rho:  array to hold the multipliers, initialized to [1.0]; the new rho will be appended
    :return: boolean success/failure indicator
"""

def loss_fun(x):
    """
    A closure using last answer and outputs
    Simple count of wrong answers, but other forms are possible.
    :param x: The test value for rho
    :return:
    """
    res= last_answer + x * outputs
    wrong_answers = np.sum(np.argmax(res, 1) != answers)
    return wrong_answers

opt_res =optimize.minimize_scalar(loss_fun,bounds=(0,10),tol=0.01)
if not opt_res.success:
    print(f'*** rho optimization failed !!! : {opt_res.message}')
    return False
else:
    rho.append(opt_res.x)

last_answer = last_answer + rho[-1] * outputs

return True
```